# udp recv gives this error... 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recvfrom'

Tags: python, sockets, pycharm, udp

I'm using PyCharm. I'm trying to make a UDP client/server where the client sends the server the some video (camera web), and the server prints it.

When trying to run the code in regular mode, I get this error:

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recvfrom'

but when using debug mode, it all works fine.

**the client code:**

```
import cv2, imutils, socket
import numpy as np
import time
import base64
import threading


HOST = '192.168.56.1'
PORT = 9999
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFF_SIZE = 65536


def send_vid(client_socket):
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # replace 'rocket.mp4' with 0 for webcam
    WIDTH = 400
    while(vid.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=WIDTH)
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 80])
        message = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        client_socket.sendto(message, ADDR)
        cv2.imshow('SENDING VID', frame) #change if only sends

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            client_socket.sendto("+DISCONNECT".encode("utf-8"), ADDR)
            client_socket.close()
            break



if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
    client_socket.sendto(b'hello', ADDR)
    print(f"[CONNECTED] : connected to {ADDR}")
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=send_vid, args={client_socket})
    t1.start()
```

**the server code:**

```
import cv2, imutils, socket
import numpy as np
import time
import base64
import threading

HOST = '192.168.56.1'
PORT = 9999
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFF_SIZE = 65536


def recv_vid(server_socket, client_addr):
    while True:
        try:
            packet, _ = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)#<------------- this is where the error
            data = base64.b64decode(packet, ' /')
            npdata = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint8)
            frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata, 1)
            cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO", frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            #print(f"[DISCONNECT] : {client_addr} disconnected")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
    server_socket.bind(ADDR)
    print(f"[SERVER INIT] : server is ready {ADDR}")
    WIDTH = 400
    while True:
        msg, client_addr = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        if msg == b'hello':
            print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] : {client_addr}')
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_vid, args={server_socket, client_addr})
            t1.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Python, but just about every example I can find of `threading.Thread` uses *parenthesis* to pass parameters to thread functions.  But you are using *curly braces* instead.

Try this:

Change:
`t1 = threading.Thread(target=send_vid, args={client_socket})`
to:
`t1 = threading.Thread(target=send_vid, args=(client_socket,))`

Change:
`t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_vid, args={server_socket, client_addr})`
to:
`t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_vid, args=(server_socket, client_addr))`